# Debug won't stop at breakpoints?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I'm new to C++, and in fact this is my first assignment in college for it

My problem is that I wrote what I thought would work but running without debugging does not seem to make it work and local debugging skips over any and all breakpoints I make on the code. I don't think it's a problem with the code, maybe a software issue, but here is the code anyways.

```
#include <iostream>;
using namespace std;
//using namespace std;

// Declare named constants, as necessary.
const double CENTIMETERS_PER_INCH = 2.54;
const int INCHES_PER_YARD         = 36;
const int INCHES_PER_FOOT         = 12;

int main()
{
    // Declare named variables, as necessary.
    double inputCentimeters;
    int inches;
    int feet;
    int yards;

    // Executable statement(s).
    cout << "Give me a length in centimeters: ";
    cin  >> inputCentimeters; 
    cout << endl;

    inches = static_cast<int>((inputCentimeters + 0.5) / CENTIMETERS_PER_INCH);
    yards  = inches / INCHES_PER_YARD;
    inches = inches % INCHES_PER_YARD;
    feet   = inches / INCHES_PER_FOOT;
    inches = inches % INCHES_PER_FOOT;

    cout << yards  << " yard(s),"
         << feet   << " feet (foot),"
         << inches << " inch(es).";

    return 0;
}
```

I'm running Microsoft Visual Studio 11 on Windows 8

Comment: Oh and I built it and it showed no errors or anything, just up-to-date

Comment: Are you sure you really have [Visual Studio 11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012), which I believe was a developer preview version? If so, then you are using a preview software, which might well have bugs etc... I suggest you get the released version, probably Visual Studio Express 2012...

Comment: "does not seem to make it work" - can we get something a little less nebulous than that. *Why* do you say that? Errors reported? Incorrect results? Running from the IDE without a debugger, as soon as this program finishes it will close the console window so you likely won't have time to see your results regardless.

Comment: Oh, and a stupid queston: Did you "run" the program, or "debug" the program? If you selected "run", then it will be run stand-alone, not inside debugger... You must "debug" the project if you want to run the program in debugger. (Note: "run" and "debug" might be named differently in the menus in your VS, but I hope you get the idea.)

Comment: I may be too obvious, but make sure you click debug, not run. I've got trapped into this one time

Comment: Do the breakpoints show a message like "The breakpoint will not be currently hit"? You should see why the breakpoint wasn't hit when you go with the mouse over the breakpoint icon.

Comment: You don't need a debugger. Pick an input and step through the computation "by hand" - it's only five lines - writing down the values of each variable as they change with each assignment.

Comment: a) yeah I'm using 2012,  it's just called Visual Studio 11 for some reason

b) I'm trying to get the command window to come up with the cout stuff but it skips right through or gives "press any key to continue..."

c) I don't even know if there is a "run" button, I was told it should work as "start without debugging"

Comment: As @hyde points out there are two options to run your program - run it without debugging which is triggered by ctrl+f5or debug it, which is triggered by f5

Comment: @TheDrZamboni *"I was told it should work as "start without debugging"* You were told that breakpoints should work when you ask VS to "start without debugging"? Well, either you understood wrong, or you were told wrong... I think the words "start without debugging" are rather self-explanatory, really.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to start an application: with debugging and without debugging.
When starting without debugging, the debugger is not attached. Without the Debugger attached when the application runs it will not hit Breakpoints, emit Debug messages.

You can read more here. There are also some screenshots which may help:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/11/01/start-debugging-vs-start-without-debugging-vstipdebug0037.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio by default create projects in two configurations - Debug and Release. Main difference with these configurations to you is you can debug app in first configuration and cannot in second one. If you choose Debug configuration from drop-down on your standard toolbar and then use "Start debugging" from menu (or press standard hotkey F5 for this) you could be ok with debugging. Also, read great [article about debugging](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn) in Visual Studio. Is is about VS2010 but i am pretty sure it could be useful for you with 2011 version.